# XSLT foreach default value

Tags: xml, xslt

## XML

```
  <CodeLists>
    <CodeList Code="Add" Description="Add1"  />
    <CodeList  Code="city" Description="City"  />
     <CodeList  Code="Name" Description="Names"  />
  </CodeLists>
```

## XSLT

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/CodeLists/CodeList">
    <option>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
             <xsl:value-of select="@Code"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
    </option
 </xsl:for-each>
```

I get result like below in my dropdown (Alphabetic order)
 But i want to have the default value to be City in dropdown. How can i do
 that?

Add1
   City
   Names

I tried  adding the below clause in xslt but its not setting the Name as the default value.

```
  <xsl:if test="@Code = 'Name'">
      <xsl:attribute name="selected">1</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
```

Comment: You wrote that you like City to be selected, your code selects Name. Is that the problem?;-)

Comment: And is the 1 really necessary?

Comment: No i want  Name by default to be selected, but the first value Add1 is selected by default

Comment: Could you add your transformed output?

Comment: Whereabouts did you add you add your `xsl:if` code? It needs to go before the `<xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>`.

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="/CodeLists/CodeList">
    <option>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
             <xsl:value-of select="@Code"/>
        </xsl:attribute> <xsl:if test="@Code = 'Name'">
      <xsl:attribute name="selected">1</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
    </option
 </xsl:for-each

Answer (score 1):

If you want city to be selected, this should work:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/CodeLists/CodeList">
    <option>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
             <xsl:value-of select="@Code"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="@Code = 'city'">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
    </option>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Also, no sure why `city` is lower case in the xml, but just going off of your provided code. You might want to keep that consistent.